# Webbrowser module in cgi python

Tags: python, cgi

I want to make a simple program that takes input from the user and then opens a webpage with that info. I am a complete newby to cgi, but have a bit of python experience. I have run the following script with a local cgi server.

This is what my main file that launches the webpage looks like:

```
#!usr/bin/env/python
import re
import webbrowser
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
input_from_user = form.getvalue('input_from_html')
product_numbers =  re.split(';', input_from_user)

for i in product_numbers:
    launch_code = "http://www.proshop.dk/" + i
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(launch_code)
```

I have another file that is responsible for the form and the input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print """Content-type: text/html

<form method="post" action="proshopapp.py">
<textarea name="input_from_html" cols="40" rows="5">
Enter comments here...
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>"""
```

Nothing happens when i press the button. But i have tested that the input is received. I want the webbrowser to launch the links, that i pass to it.

Comment: "Nothing happens": you need to understand what you expect to happen, step-by-step, and check each of these steps.  For example, when you press the button, the web browser should go to the url "relative/path/proshopapp.py": does it do that?  If yes, you can add to proshopapp.py a command that saves log in a file, and see if they appear.  If no, then it's an html issue, e.g. you may need to go to a "http://" url (and not a file://, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function:

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab()
```

will work in scripts for opening a new tab in a local browser; however, this will not work with cgi scripts to open a new browser tab on the client side. Instead, rewrite your "proshopapp.py" file to generate a webpage with [javascript to open new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript).